# Adding a checkbox with delete option with jQuery for an array of elements

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and JS. I have been wondering how to add a checkbox for each of the elements in the array `aCurrencies`, so I can be able to delete one or many of the elements in this array.  My idea is to do this with the `for loop` I already have in the method below.

I made many unsuccessful attempts to code this, so any input will be highly appreciated.

```
function showHideCurrencies() {
    $("#lblCurrencies").empty();
    if (bShown == 0) {
        $("#btnShowHideCurrencies").text("HIDE CURRENCIES");
        bShown = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < aCurrencies.length; i++) {
            $("#lblCurrencies").append("<div>" + aCurrencies[i] + "<i data-arrayIndex='" + i + "' class='fa fa-trash-o fa-fw'></i></div>")
        }
        $("#lblCurrencies").show();
    } else {
        $("#btnShowHideCurrencies").text("SHOW CURRENCIES");
        bShown = 0;
        $("#lblCurrencies").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is not so much clear.. Do you mean you want to add checkboxes into your HTML via your `foreach` loop ?

Comment: I am sorry about that. Yes, this is what I mean. Of course, if there is a better option - I am open.

Comment: where you want to add into your this label => `lblCurrencies` ?

Comment: yes, in the very same label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have prepared a demo code like below:

**HTML:**

```
<label id="lblCurrencies"></label>
<button id="btnShowHideCurrencies">

</button>
```

**JQuery:**

```
var bShown=0;
var aCurrencies=["first","second","third"];
showHideCurrencies();
function showHideCurrencies() {
    $("#lblCurrencies").empty();
    if (bShown == 0) {
        $("#btnShowHideCurrencies").text("HIDE CURRENCIES");
        bShown = 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < aCurrencies.length; i++) {
            $("#lblCurrencies").append("<div class>" + aCurrencies[i] + "<i data-arrayIndex='" + i + "' class='fa fa-trash-o fa-fw'></i><input type='checkbox' id='chk_"+i+"' /></div>")
        }
        $("#lblCurrencies").show();
    } else {
        $("#btnShowHideCurrencies").text("SHOW CURRENCIES");
        bShown = 0;
        $("#lblCurrencies").hide();
    }    

}
```

this code will add Checkboxes with Unique Id into your `Label`.

You can see demo on fiddle [Click here.](https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/bmnfLhb9/)

Hope it helps you